# Hiding Hashable in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

How can I return `[Hashable: Any]` where the concrete type implementing `Hashable` is hidden?

Swift has two types of protocols: Those that can be used as types and those that can only be used as type constraints. While this is powerful, it is also unfortunate. It means that certain types of information hiding are not directly possible.

The only solution I could come up with is to use a thunk:

```
struct Hash: Hashable {
    private let value: Any
    private let equals: Hash -> Bool

    init<H: Hashable>(_ h: H) {
        self.value = h
        self.hashValue = h.hashValue
        self.equals = { ($0.value as! H) == h }
    }

    let hashValue: Int
}

func ==(lhs: Hash, rhs: Hash) -> Bool {
    return lhs.equals(rhs)
}
```

Perhaps someday Swift will create thunks like this for us. That is after all one of the things compilers are for.

Is this the only way? Am I missing something?

Comment: The Swift standard library does similar things with `AnySequence`, `AnyGenerator` as type-erased `Sequence/GeneratorType`.

Comment: Yes, sadly I think this is the only way. I just dislike that it's a thunk. I'd love to see the compiler do this somehow, though for any arbitrary constraint-bound protocol it may not be possible for the compiler to determine how to "thunk" it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is that swift protocols like `Hashable` can be applied to all different types, not just classes.

Let's say we have two different types: a struct which takes up 8 bits of memory and a class which is a pointer to some chunk of memory on the heap.

```
struct HashyStruct : Equatable, Hashable {
    let smallNumber: UInt16
    var hashValue: Int {
        return Int(smallNumber)
    }
}
func ==(lhs: HashyStruct, rhs: HashyStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.smallNumber == rhs.smallNumber
}


class HashyClass : Equatable, Hashable {
    let number: UInt64
    init(number: UInt64) {
        self.number = number
    }
    var hashValue: Int {
        return Int(number)
    }
}
func ==(lhs: HashyClass, rhs: HashyClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.number == rhs.number
}
```

Both of these types are `Hashable`, so why can't we have an dictionary like this:

```
let anyHashable: [Hashable:Any] = [HashyStruct(smallNumber: 5) : "struct", HashyClass(number: 0x12345678):"class"]
```

> error: using 'Hashable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported
>   error: protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

`Dictionary` needs to be able to compare objects to each other to resolve conflicts where two things have the same hash value. How would it compare a `HashyStruct` to a `HashyClass`? It has no idea which function to call to compare the two objects. It doesn't know whether to call `hashValue` on `HashyStruct` or `HashyClass`.

### But Objective-C does it...

You can actually implement this if you want to do it dynamically at runtime. The "thunk" you implemented does have that sort of dynamic behavior but it comes with a performance hit that in most cases you don't need to take.

### More juicy hash table details which aren't super important but help you understand

I'm assuming you know how hash tables are implemented as a fixed size array and the hash value is mapped to a limited number of buckets which can have conflicts.

`Dictionary` allocates a chunk of memory to store it's objects; lets give it 4 portions of 64 bytes each (the size of a pointer on 64 bit machines).

`| 64 bytes | 64 bytes | 64 bytes | 64 bytes |`

When you add two items with hash values 1 and 6 = 2 % 4 you'll get the following hash table:

`| empty | item 1 | item 2 | empty |`

That's all well and good; we can fit any number of pointer objects into our table which will work for classes. But in swift we have structs - `HashyStruct` only has 16 bits. If we gave the same amount of memory to a dictionary storing `HashyStruct`s then we could store 16 instead of 4 items in our hash set.

`| 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes | 16 bytes |`

As long as the compiler knows the size of the type we can have any type we want in a hash table. But when we have two different types...???

`| 4 structs | item 1 | item 2 | empty |`

You get a hash table which makes no sense. The compiler doesn't know the size of the items in the array so it can't index them.

A lot of what makes swift great is that you aren't tied to classes and objects allocated on the heap. It by default gives you good performance and you opt into dynamic behavior if you need it.

Comment: Great answer, though not quite what I was looking for. What makes my question sadder is that I actually understand all this, but I think it will be instructive to those newer to Swift than we are. I was just hoping there was something in the language I missed that would make this possible. I don't want this for heterogeneous types, though. Instead, I want it just to hide the underlying type, i.e., I want a kind of "opaque hashable key" where the user does not know what the real underlying type is. I think a thunk is the only way to do it.

Comment: So you're trying to hide the actual object so the user can't see/modify it? Is that what your end goal?

Comment: Yes. The type I want to hide is actually a struct called `Key`, but for various reasons it's uncool if the user sees any of its state. There are two ways, I think, to do this. First, I could use a thunk, as above. Second, I could make all of `Key`'s state private except to the other types that use it, by placing them all in the same compilation unit. Unless of course I get my wish and Swift has some other way around this I haven't seen. :)

Comment: Is it possible to add `Key` to the user's value and just use a set of Values? I'm a little uncertain on the specifics of your situation tbh

Comment: If the value the user wants to store conforms to one of your protocols or is a subclass of something you provide I think you could add an object privately

Comment: I'm writing a dependency resolution framework called [Guise](https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/develop/Guise/Guise.swift). When the user registers a dependency, I want its key returned as an opaque, hashable value. The compromise I made was simply to make the type public but make its state private.